# Custom foreign key & local key in hasMany relation : Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to use hasMany relation with raw sql foreign key and local key. I have to relate them on the basis of date that's why I have to use raw sql functions as foreign key and local key.

I've tried to customize the hasMany relation but no success.

```
public function auctionVehicles()
{
    return $this->customHasMany(
        'App\Models\ManheimVehicle',
        \DB::raw("SUBSTRING(sale_date, 1, 10)"),
        \DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(
             STR_TO_DATE(auction_date,'%b %d, %Y'), '%d/%m/%Y')")
        )
    );
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you post the relevant database structure?

Comment: sale_date is in  => 08/08/2019 - 11:30 AM ET format 
& auction_date is in  => Aug 07, 2019 format

Comment: Please explain what is the error. And the function `customHasMany()` is not in the laravel source, can you post the relevant code.

Comment: I was trying to customize the hasMany relation, but was not able to get this work. What I want is not to use ids as foreign and local keys but instead raw query functions i.e. DATE_FORMAT because I have to relate them through dates.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand why are you using this `customHasMany` with a raw query and what's your issue exactly, but I guess you're looking for this:

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```

You can use the second and third argument to override the default foreign key and local key on relationships.